# Ruby/Rails get start, end date of a given week number of year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Base on the doc, I was able to get the current week number of current year :

```
Time.current.strftime('%V') => "23"
```

But I need methods that I can retrieve start date, end date of a given week number.
In this example : `2016/06/06 -> 2016/06/12`

any idea ?

Comment: @Stefan nothing like that even i give upvotre to correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you need to use [`::commercial` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial) from `Date` class like this.

```
require 'date'

week = 23
start_week = Date.commercial(2016, week, 1)
# => #<Date: 2016-06-06 ((2457546j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

end_week = Date.commercial(2016, week, 7)
# => #<Date: 2016-06-12 ((2457552j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

And if you want to print as you  show in your example, do:

```
puts "#{start_week} -> #{end_week}"
# => 2016-06-06 -> 2016-06-12
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial

Comment: this IS what I need

Comment: @DuongBach Here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial

Comment: In case you need a range, there's also `Date.commercial(2016, week).all_week`

Answer (score 0):

```
p "#{(Time.now + ((Time.current.strftime('%V').to_i) * 7).days).beginning_of_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} -> #{(Time.now + ((Time.current.strftime('%V').to_i) * 7).days).end_of_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"
```

Comment: The OP is looking for [week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week_number) 23, not 23 weeks from now.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below functions:

```
Date.now.beginning_of_week
Date.now.end_of_week
```

Comment: This code give me begin and end of THIS week, not given week number

Comment: Do you need week number? or date of start of week? or number of week in the duration?

Comment: what output you want if a=2016/06/06 b= 2016/06/12

Comment: I want input number 23 and output a, b like u just listed out